# Is it possible to create a telegram bot which forwards messages from another bot to telegram group or channel?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I want to create a telegram bot which would immediately forward message from another bot, that regularly posts some info. I've tried to find some ready templates, but alas... I would be grateful for any useful info. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this due to API limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. As far as I know, bots can't communicate with other bots.

But you can add bots to groups

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if i haven't admin rights in bot, i want to forward messages from, it's impossible to solve this task. I'm right?

Comment: you can add bots to groups and apparently also to channels. Then you can forward any message. Otherwise you have to do it manually. I don't know any other way, sorry